# XML.toString(jsonObject) in thr org.json jar is trimming tailing zero

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

`XML.toString(jsonObject)` in the `org.json` jar is trimming tailing zero.
for example

```
{
"somekey":300.10,
"somekey1":300.00,
}
```

Conveting the above json to xml results in

```
<somekey>300.1</somekey>
<somekey1>300.0</somekey1>
```

How can I preserve it from trimming that zero

Comment: `300.10` and `300.1` is the same *number*. If you want to keep 2 decimals, then you don't want a *number*, but the *text* representation of a number, e.g. `"300.10"`.

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert xml to json. U.xmlToJson(xml) method will help.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the values to the `JSONObject` as `String` instead of `double`:

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("someKey", "300.10" );
jsonObject.put("somekey1", "300.00" );
final String xml = XML.toString(jsonObject);
```

This will preserve the ending zeros.

Comment: The json is not controlled by me. It is a result of a webservice call

Comment: @Srigandan Then you need to format it to 2 decimals.

Comment: If it is for one or 2 fields I can do it. But there are multiple services and each service has multiple fields of such type. Is this is an issue from the library file itself?

Comment: XML.toString() uses simply toString() of the Objects. I wouldn't call this an issue...

Comment: Why don't you write a static utils method, that replaces `double` or `float` values in `JSONObeject`s with either `String` or applies a format to it? If the impact on performance is not too bad...

Answer (score 0):

You could use jackson XmlMapper and write and register a DuoubleSerializer with the format the suits your needs.

```
public class XmlTest {

    public static class SimpleBean {
        Double a;
        Double b;

        public Double getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(Double a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public Double getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(Double b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public SimpleBean(Double a, Double b) {
            super();
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

    }

    public static class DoubleSerializer extends StdSerializer<Double> {

        public DoubleSerializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public DoubleSerializer(Class<Double> t) {
            super(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeRaw(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.2f", value));
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Double.class, new DoubleSerializer());
        xmlMapper.registerModule(module);

        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new SimpleBean(1.50, 1.60)));
    }

}
```